# Swift - Adding image to tableview cell from asset library

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add an image to a tableview cell but not having much luck getting it to display.

The image is being loaded from the file system (I `println()` the result) as a UIImage but I cannot seem to get it into the cell. Placing a `println()` after the closure shows me that the images are all loaded after the cell has been returned.

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    let note = notes[indexPath.row]
    let nsURL = NSURL(string: note.valueForKey("url") as! String)!
    var loadError: NSError?
    var image: UIImage?

    assetsLibrary!.assetForURL(nsURL, resultBlock: { (asset) -> Void in
            if let ast = asset {
                let iref = ast.defaultRepresentation().fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue()
                image = UIImage(CGImage: iref)
                println("The loaded image: \(image)")
            }
        }, failureBlock: {(error) -> Void in
            loadError = error
        })

    cell.textLabel!.text = note.valueForKey("title") as? String
    cell.imageView!.image = image

    return cell
}
```

When I replace the closure with the following to load a image from the project itself it shows in the table. This leads me to believe it not due to an issue with the way the story board is set up.

```
UIImage(named: transportItems[indexPath.row])
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to see whether the line 'cell.imageView!.image = image' is getting called after 'image = UIImage(CGImage: iref)'?  Try moving cell.textLabel.image = image into the block...  If this works, I can write up an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue I was encountering, as pointed out by @gnasher729, was the mishmash of synchronous and asynchronous calls. Rewriting the code to take this into account and to include a cache, I have the following working solution.

```
var cachedImages = [String:UIImage]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
    let note = notes[indexPath.row]
    let url = note.valueForKey("url") as! String

    cell.textLabel!.text = note.valueForKey("title") as? String
    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "note-icon")

    if let image = cachedImages[url]{
        cell.imageView!.image = image
    } else {
        let nsURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        var loadError: NSError?

        assetsLibrary!.assetForURL(nsURL, resultBlock: { (asset) -> Void in
            if let ast = asset {
                let image = UIImage(CGImage: ast.defaultRepresentation().fullResolutionImage().takeUnretainedValue())
                self.cachedImages[url] = image

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                        cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
                    }
                })

            }
            },failureBlock: {(error) -> Void in
                loadError = error
        })
    }
    return cell
}
```

This could be further improved to take more off of the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way. cellForRowAtPathIndex is a synchronous routine. assetForURL is an asynchronous routine. It will return the data long time after cellForRowAtPathIndex has returned.

Here's what you should do: Have a method cachedAssetForURL which returns the asset immediately, or returns nil. If it returns an asset, store it. Remember this has to be as efficient as possible, because this is called while the user scrolls up and down through the images.

If the method returns nil, trigger a download in the background. When that download finishes, don't even try to store the image in the cell - by this time, the same cell could display an entirely different object! Instead store the data so that cachedAssetForURL will be able to return the asset, and invalidate the row of your table view.

Comment: Awesome, thats really helped me to understand the root of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fire a notification in the block (it's asynchronous), manage it by setting your imageview and reload your view.